# Не верно сохраняет кодировку

Tags: c#

Не верно сохраняет кодировку при считывании, и далее она используется при записи. Заглавные буквы переходят почему-то в обычные и удаляется тире.До считывания  и после записи

```
if (xDoc.Declaration != null)
                            string declaration = xDoc.Declaration.Encoding.ToString();

 XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));
                XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("", "");
                //получаем поток, куда будем записывать сериализованный объект 
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathXmlFileWrite, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = false, Indent = true, Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(declaration) });
                    formatter.Serialize(writer, report, ns);
                }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем вы делаете кодировке `ToString()`?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov При считывании файла мне нужно сохранить его кодировку, я решил сохранить в строку, и потом при записи xml эту кодировку мне надо использовать..

Comment: Так `ToString()`-то зачем?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov В смысле зачем!? Вы не знаете этот метод?

Comment: @SVD102, приложите пожалуйста xmldeclaration после запись в файл.

Comment: @ Alexcei Shmakov Не понял

Comment: @SVD102, вы записываете объект в файл. Приведите строку подобно вот этой <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?> Какая у вас там строка? И приведите значение переменной declaration, вытащенной из объетка xDoc?

Comment: @ Alexcei Shmakov Выложил скриншоты. Строка как на 2 скриншоте. На 1 скришоте открыт файл до его считывания, и там как я понял кодировка ANSI, а наверху файла указано encoding="ISO8859-1". И я записываю используя кодировку ISO8859-1. Наверно в этом ошибка

Comment: @SVD102, вы какую кодировку передаете? чему равна переменная declaration?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36448/discussion-between-svd102-and-alexcei-shmakov).

Answer (score 1):

Это нормально. Если множество способов записать имя одной и той же кодировки. `XmlWriter` записывает то, которое является стандартным.

Comment: Что нормально???

Comment: То, как записывается кодировка в выходной файл.

Comment: имя кодировки одно - и ее правильное название iso-8859-1, и никаких множество способов нет.

Answer (score 0):

Кодировка ISo8859-1 NotePad не распознал, так правильное название кодировки **Latin-1 - [iso-8859-1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1)**
В связи с этим он вам открыл файл в кодировке ANSI.
Когда же вы указали верный тип кодировки, то NotePad файл с кодировкой iso-8859-1. Вы сохраняете файл с несуществующим названием кодировки, поэтому он берет ее по-умолчанию.